# Query MySQL (SQL server) in parallel from python

Tags: python, sql, parallel-processing

I have collection of objects and each object I would like to populate with some data from MySQL (could be SQL Server). I would like to do in parallel fashion. When establishing connection to MySQL I have two items

1. connection
2. cursor

Hence, the question, when making calls in parallel, should I pass

1. connection only
2. cursor only
3. connection and cursor only
4. do not pass anything and let each object's method establish connection on its own.

---------------code formatting does not work without this line -------

```
import mysql.connector

my_collection = [My_Object(), My_Object()]

config = {'user': 'someuser', 'password': 'somepassword', 'host': 'localhost', 'port': '3306',
'database': 'somedb','raise_on_warnings': True}

connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)

#some parallel loop
for el in my_collection:
    el.pull_data_from(WHAT TO PASS???)
```

Comment: How many objects do you have? Setting up connections to the DB is expensive and most have connection limits. Is there any reason in your app why you would require a new connection and or cursor for each object?

Comment: @Ed Baker All I want to do is to query SQL in parallel. If it is possible to do it without creating new connection or cursor, I will take it.

Comment: So what you want to do is use a db connection pool, if you're in python Django will take care of this for you. Using someone else's connection pool code is much easier than implementing it yourself.

Comment: @EdBaker Thank you! I am not familiar with Django. Immediate search does not return any easy example, so I guess I have to spend time reading about Django and possibly SQLAlchemy

Comment: no problems, enjoy the learning!